# Kickstarter confirmation emails don't arrive in Gmail

Tags: gmail, verification, kickstarter

I'm trying to start a [Kickstarter project](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1428239507/301301810?ref=preview&token=3fa015c7). Kickstarter requires verification through a confirmation email.

I've been through the process several times and I cannot locate the email anywhere in Gmail, including Trash and Spam; and Categories like Promotions and Updates. I've searched for `no-reply@kickstarter.com in:all`, `no_reply@kickstarter.com in:all`, `kickstarter.com in:all` and several others that seemed to make sense. `kickstarter.com in:all` found the emails that I knew about from my inbox, but not the confirmation emails.

I found an old post about the problem on Google Product Forums at [Cannot get emails from no-r...@kickstarter.com](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/u-YKWi0J0oo). Unfortunately, there were no answers provided.

What are the problems with Kickstarter verification emails and Gmail? How do I work around the problems?

Comment: Are you using a redirect through a custom domain (e.g. emails to mail@yourproject.com are forwarded to your Gmail address)?

Comment: I have the same issue, and yes, I use custom domain with forward to Gmail. I did not have such issues until a month or two. Any hint on how to fix it?